# 100% Browser Width Div Inside Smaller Div

Tags: css, html, width

I have a div of `width: 1000px` and inside that is a child which I wish to span the entire width of the browser window.

The trouble is, I don't know how to override previous width inheritance.

I could just position this outside of my container div, but that would be a huge inconvenience and workaround, unless of course this is equally as troublesome.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="centreContainer">

    <div class="menuContainer"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.centreContainer
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

.menuContainer
{
    width: <what to do>;
    height: 420px;
}
```

Preferably I would like a CSS only workaround, I was thinking of some stupid Javascript solution where you get the width of the browser window, then set the width of the menuContainer to:

`<variable> / 10` *(10 because 1000 / 100 = 10, where 1000 is the width of the centre container)*

And have the menuContainer set on `margin: auto;` so it is centered.

Comment: You can't override that in simple way. That's how CSS is meant to work. If you use 100% inside 1000px it will always be 1000px.

Comment: And your JS idea is the only idea to go :)

Comment: @DainisAbols I was afraid of this, but I just had to ask anyway to double check. I suppose deep down I was hoping it wasn't that easy because as you say, that's how CSS is supposed to work.

Comment: @tsujp What exactly are you trying to achieve? Tell us and we might give you an alternative way to do that.

Comment: @DainisAbols a page with a centre div, containing all content, which is 1000px wide. Inside this centre div, or arranged in such another way, another div spans the entire width of the browser window. I'll just position the div outside, and have the centre divided into 'above' and 'below' this browser-wide element, or try my Javascript method.

Comment: You can close the 1000px div, create a 100% div and then reopen the previous one. This would be the best practice.

Comment: Yeah I'll just go ahead and do that. Thanks for the insight man. The more you know.

Comment: Let's just remember that <table> never had these horrific constant issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position`:

```
.menuContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
}
```

Comment: Already tried these, remember I have set the margin to auto `margin: auto;` and it thus get's set 50% of the width. Setting `margin-left: -50%` doesn't solve the problem either haha.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position:absolute` shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygGvm/)

```
.menuContainer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px; 
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Already tried these, remember I have set the margin to auto `margin: auto;` and it thus get's set 50% of the width. Setting `margin-left: -50%` doesn't solve the problem either haha.

Answer (score 0):

you could try placing your .menuContainer as absolute position into a relative parent position . [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rJ7h/)

```
#root{
display:block;
position: relative;
```

}

```
.menuContainer{
position:absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0;
```

}